# Difference between createSelector(...) and () => createSelector(...)

Tags: reactjs, select, redux, reselect

Can anyone tell me the difference between these two type of usage of the reselectors, and tell me when to use which?

```
// First type of selector, without arrow function
export const selectMyValue = createSelector(
  rootSelector,
  state => state.get('someValue'),
)

// Second type of selector, with arrow function
export const selectMyValue = () => createSelector(
  rootSelector,
  state => state.get('someValue'),
)
```

Comment: The difference comes down to Javascript declarations vs expressions and hoisting, a good explanation can be found here: https://gomakethings.com/function-expressions-vs-function-declarations/

Answer (score 4):

> difference between these two type

The first example assign `selectMyValue` to whatever `createSelector` is returning. Therefore you can call it with your state:

```
const value = selectMyValue(someState)
```

Whereas the second example is returning a function that **wrapped** the `createSelector`. But the `createSelector` is not called yet. You will use that function to call it later:

```
const wrapped = selectMyValue();
const value = wrapped(someState);
```

or one liner:

```
const value = selectMyValue()(someState);
```

---

> when to use which?

You will probably going to use the first one in most cases. However there may arise some case when you need to provide some arguments to your wrapper function.

For example:

```
export const selectMyValue = (value) => createSelector(
  rootSelector,
  state => state[value] // just an example
)
```

Here your wrapper takes an argument named `value`. You can call it as utility to extract different parts of state:

```
const valueFromState = selectMyValue('someValue')(state);
const someOtherValueFromState = selectMyValue('someOtherValue')(state);
```

Comment: Hey @ReidunMarie, if this answer seems helpful to you, would you take a moment to [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Comment: I use the wrapper function when I call it within mapStateToProps. This way you can directly bind your selectors to your props very efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

The **first one** is a **simple selector** directly consumable by your application like:

```
selectMyValue(state);
```

The **second one** is a [**selector factory**](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect/tree/v4.0.0#q-how-do-i-create-a-selector-that-takes-an-argument), in other words a function which returns a totally new selector instance on every call.

```
const selectMyValue1 = selectMyValueFactory();
const selectMyValue2 = selectMyValueFactory();

// Calls to the following selectors won't invalidate each other's cache
selectMyValue1(state);
selectMyValue2(state);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect .
See chapter: Sharing Selectors with Props Across Multiple Component Instances.
Reason of creating selector factory also is described above the chapter:

> A selector created with createSelector has a cache size of 1 and only
> returns the cached value when its set of arguments is the same as its
> previous set of arguments. If we alternate between rendering
> `<VisibleTodoList listId="1" />` and `<VisibleTodoList listId="2" />`, the
> shared selector will alternate between receiving {listId: 1} and
> {listId: 2} as its props argument. This will cause the arguments to be
> different on each call, so the selector will always recompute instead
> of returning the cached value. We’ll see how to overcome this
> limitation in the next section.

Another words, you need create own cached selector for each instance of component.